# D3 circle object has no properties

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, properties

I'm working on a special type of map with D3, which combines polygons and points.

For that, I use two json file. The first one, with polygons, is formated like this :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "101", "name": "Place 1", "common_property":"P1" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [   bla bla bla ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "102", "name": "Place 2", "common_property":"P1" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [   bla bla bla ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "103", "name": "Place 3", "common_property":"P2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [   bla bla bla ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

On the other hand, I've got this json file with my points :

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "common_property": "P1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.741, 48.58344 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "common_property": "P2" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.76840, 48.58737 ] } }
]}
```

My goal is to link polygons and points on mouseover baser on "common_property" vales :

- when you mouseover a polygon, the point with the same "common_property" has a different colour
- if you mouseover a points, all the polygons with the same "common_property" has the same colour.

Theorically, it's simple if I make good selections in my script. But there is something wrong with my points.

At first, I made my css sheet, and put as first variables projection, path generator, svg, etc...

Then, [I used queuejs](http://bl.ocks.org/mapsam/6090056) to read several files before my main function :

```
 queue()
    .defer(d3.json,"data/polygons.json")
    .defer(d3.json, 'data/points.json')
    .await(function(err, polygons, points) {

    THE CODE
   });
```

Inside the main function, I wrote this for displaying polygons :

```
polyg = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(polygons.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "polygon_area")
    .attr("d", path)
```

And this for displaying points :

```
places_point = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(points.features)
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .datum(function(d){
            var origin = d.geometry.coordinates
            var angle = scale*0.0000000018
            return circle.angle(angle).origin(origin)(points.features)
                      })
        .attr("class", "point")
        .attr("d", path)
```

Nothing complicated so far, exept that I've no properties for places_points variable. If I test this :

```
polyg.on('mouseover', function(d) {              
    console.log(d)
    places_point.attr("fill", function(d){
        console.log(d)})
    })
```

The console displays this :

```
Object { type: "Feature", properties: Object, geometry: Object } 

Object { type: "Polygon", coordinates: Array[1] }
Object { type: "Polygon", coordinates: Array[1] }
```

So it worked fine for polygons, there are properties and everything, but for the points I've got type "Polygon" instead of "Feature", and I don't get why very well...

**EDIT** : used v3 of D3 to made this, not the last one !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEW ANSWER FOR COMMENTS:

Ok, I knew it had to do with the `.datum` call but my initial answer was incorrect.  In this case you are re-binding your data with the `.datum` and losing your properties property.  So simply remove it and do your calculations in the path `d` assigner:

```
pt_bv = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(bv.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", function(d){
    var origin = d.geometry.coordinates
    var angle = scale * 0.0000000018
    var rV = circle.angle(angle).origin(origin)(bv.features);
    return path(rV);
  });

bureaux.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  pt_bv.attr("fill", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  })
});
```

Here's some [runnable code](http://plnkr.co/edit/twBfiwCfhPIwKjgMOq7w?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Mark, and thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately, I've juste tested the split in two declaration, but same result as before :-/

Comment: @Raphadasilva, can you create a reproducible example jsfiddle or plunker and I can take a look?

Comment: Yes, just posted a draft repo on Github, some values are named differently, but the logic is the same ! https://github.com/raphadasilva/Bakass

Comment: @Raphadasilva, see new answer above.